# Applications of ZK proofs without proof of knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

With the appearance of cryptocurrencies several applications of ZK proofs were envisioned. However, to the best of my knowledge, all of these are *proofs of knowledge*.

My question is: are there any real-world applications (in contrast to applications within cryptography) of ZK proofs without the proof of knowledge property?

Comment: I'm intrigued by your question - can you elaborate on any nascent thoughts you have about what this would theoretically look like?

Comment: ZK, stands for zero knowledge, can you elaborate further?

Comment: @JAAAY There are *zero-knowledge* proofs without the *proof of knowledge* property, the two are different.

Comment: @knaccc Within cryptography we have applications, for example, to settings where you want to prove that certain "secret" data satisfies a given predicate. For instance, in MPC it's become recently common to use (a variant of) ZK proofs to show that a set of secret-shared values satisfy certain multiplicative relation. A "real-life" application could be along similar lines: showing that some "secret" data satisfies a predicate (*e.g.* an encrypted vote can be checked to be 0 or 1, and not larger), but I'd like something more concrete and meaningful, that hopefully someone is trying out.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are excluding cryptocurrencies... Monero uses range proofs (to prove output Pedersen commitments are to positive amounts) and proofs that the sum of input Pedersen commitments equal the sum of output Pedersen commitments (to prevent inflation during opaque transactions). However, the ability to construct such proofs will implicitly prove knowledge of the values blinded by the Pedersen commitments and of the secret blinding factors.

Comment: @knaccc That's a good point. I thought most applications within the cryptocurrency space were using the PoK property. Actually, even the non-ZK applications like proving consistency of the blockchain succinctly do not really require the PoK property, am I correct?

Comment: @Daniel If you want to check for an inflation bug in bitcoin, you would add up all coinbase outputs to check the total amount of bitcoin ever mined. Then you would verify all ZK ECDSA signatures on all transactions to check they are valid, (and you'd check proper processing of all bitcoin "scripts" too), and then you'd add up all of the unspent outputs to see if they totalled the amount of bitcoin originally mined in coinbase transactions. So in terms of cryptography, that would be closer to simply verifying ZK PoK ECDSA signatures.

Comment: Also, proving the sum of two sets of Pedersen commitments are equal is essentially done by providing a simple Schnorr signature, and proving committed amounts are positive is done through a set of ring signatures. So, in these examples, even when we're proving a property of something instead of knowledge of something, we're still relying on ZK PoK proofs underneath.